# Move table down : itextsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate pdf.

My code is,

```
 public FileStreamResult Export(int ID)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Document pdf = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, stream);
        pdf.Open();
        //code for table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.SpacingBefore = 100;   //not working
        table.SpacingAfter = 10;     //not working
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");

        pdf.Add(table);


        pdf.Close();

        //code to download 
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+_child[0].Child_Name+".pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

The table appears in top of the page. but i want to move table down.How can i do?

Please Help,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to move it down by a given distance (e.g. 72 user space units), or do you want the table to be located below some other given PDF elements (e.g. the text you added in the first version of your question)?

Comment: Yes...i want to add table below some pdf elements..as in my 1st version of question

Comment: Is there a special reason why you added that other content in that 1st version by direct content manipulation instead of adding it to the PDF as `Chunk`s or `Paragraph`s? if you did the latter, your table automatically would be positioned below those paragraphs. Direct content manipulation actually is intended for adding content to a page at custom positions without changing the automatic layouting of data added to the `Document`.

Comment: when i tried using chunk, newline wasn't working. thatz y tried code in my first version.

Comment: Have you tried using `Paragraph`? Have you looked at iText in Action, 2nd edition? [Chapter 2](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) is available as a sample chapter and explains the basics. The book is written for the Java version, but it can easily be adapted to C#. The C# samples are available [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply add a '`f`' in the end of the fixed values.

Exemple:

```
table.SpacingBefore = 100f;   //is working 
table.SpacingAfter = 10f;     //is working
```